# What is the difference between disgust and antipathy?

Tags: meaning, differences, synonyms

In WikiDiff, it says antipathy is a synonym of disgust.

But as far I know antipathy is a strong dislike towards something or somebody and disgust is involuntary feeling invoking the feeling of hatred.

Can you please differentiate these two words?

Comment: ***antipathy*** is often cerebral / ideological, but ***disgust*** is primarily a *visceral* reaction.

Comment: You could say that antipathy is more head and disgust is more heart, and a much stronger word.

Comment: _Disgust_ is much closer to _revulsion_ than _antipathy_ is. In expressing antipathy for thing or person X, we might say "I can't stand X" or "I can't abide X" or even "I can't tolerate X." But in expressing disgust, we might say "I feel nauseated when I see X."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disgust is one of the universal emotions with facial expressions that are consistent across all human cultures, see [Micro Expressions](http://www.paulekman.com/micro-expressions/). It is a instinctive response to something that is either "potentially dangerous" or the opposite of what one considers normal moral values.

Disgust typically arises from how someone views bodily fluids, or slimy foods, or insects like roaches. These are all potential disease vectors, so our innate emotional response is one that warns us of it, and attempts to get us away from whatever it is disgusts us.

Antipathy however can refer to anything that someone strongly dislikes, regardless of reason. Whether it's to certain beliefs, a person, thing or activity. It's a more persistent "feeling" about something, not an immediate reaction to the environment or thought. Antipathy and disgust can go hand in hand, when for example someone who is homophobic (has antipathy for homosexuals) sees two people of the same sex together (triggering a disgust response).